# nginx folder to cdn redirection

Tags: redirect, nginx, directory, cdn, permanent

I'm still quite new to nginx and despite I took a look at all the answers of this kind of questions and tried everything they said, nothing has worked so far.

I want to do this redirection:

From
    http://www.mydomain.com/folder
to
    http://cdn.mydomain.com/folder

I have put this inside the server conf:

```
    location /folder/ {
       rewrite ^ http://cdn.mydomain.com/folder/$request_uri permanent;
    }
```

I think I am near but still don't get where I am wrong.

In my old server, using this .htaccess inside each folder works fine:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule (.*) http://cdn.mydomain.com/folder/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently matching only the exact location `/folder/`. You should edit that to match all locations beginning with `/folder/`:

```
location ^~ /folder/ {
```

Also, your rewrite has one and a half errors. If I request `http://www.mydomain.com/folder/123.png`, then you will redirect me to `http://cdn.mydomain.com/folder//folder/123.png`, which is most probably not correct. Below is the complete location and rewrite directive. The question mark after `$request_uri` makes sure that a potential query string only gets added once.

```
location ^~ /folder/ {
   rewrite ^ http://cdn.mydomain.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Comment: hey Bro, So I'm at this stage where I need the exact thing but 5% different I think.  I want my users to hit ``http://embed.mydomain.com/embed.js`` and then I want the file on my S3  to be served. How do I do this please ?